# How to convert date format using bash and printf?

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I want to convert `2019-02-16` to `Feb 16 15:29` in bash using `awk` and `printf`.

For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# who | awk '{print $1, $3, $4}'
root 2019-02-16 15:29
root 2019-02-16 15:30
john 2019-02-01 10:34
emmett 2019-01-12 09:45
```

Desired output:

```
root Feb 16 15:29
root Feb 16 15:30
john Feb 1  10:34
emmett Jan 12 09:45
```

Please help and provide an explanation with your solution.

Comment: If nobody comes up with an elegant solution, you could make something ugly starting from ```date --date=$(who | awk '{print $3, $4}')```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 2):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ who | awk '{split($3,d,/-/); print $1, substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(d[2]*3)-2,3), d[3]+0, $4}'
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
root 2019-02-16 15:29
root 2019-02-16 15:30
john 2019-02-01 10:34
emmett 2019-01-12 09:45

$ awk '{split($2,d,/-/); print $1, substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(d[2]*3)-2,3), d[3]+0, $3}' file
root Feb 16 15:29
root Feb 16 15:30
john Feb 1 10:34
emmett Jan 12 09:45
```

and if alignment matters there's various solutions, including using printf instead of print:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{split($2,d,/-/); printf "%s %s %-2d %s\n", $1, substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(d[2]*3)-2,3), d[3]+0, $3}' file
root Feb 16 15:29
root Feb 16 15:30
john Feb 1  10:34
emmett Jan 12 09:45
```

or separate the output with tabs instead of blanks:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{split($2,d,/-/); print $1, substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(d[2]*3)-2,3), d[3]+0, $3}' file
root    Feb     16      15:29
root    Feb     16      15:30
john    Feb     1       10:34
emmett  Jan     12      09:45
```

or pipe the output to `column -t`:

```
$ awk '{split($2,d,/-/); print $1, substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(d[2]*3)-2,3), d[3]+0, $3}' file | column -t
root    Feb  16  15:29
root    Feb  16  15:30
john    Feb  1   10:34
emmett  Jan  12  09:45
```

Comment: Nice use of a run-string dictionary offset lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime()`

```
$ who | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F '[-]' '{ print $1, strftime ("%b %d %H:%M", systime()) }'
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think so. The first one is needed to get the user only, while eliminating the others.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for time functions. Also systime() will tell you the current time on your system - you need to use mktime() instead to convert the time from the input into seconds since the epoch. There's also a couple of syntax errors with curly braces in the wrong place and missing parens. And finally - obviously that can't produce the expected multi-fields output given it only works on 1 of the input fields.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, especially for the missing first parentheses that I forgot to put 
 just after `strftime` and the first curly brace, now I fixed.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll still just print the time when the tool is executed rather than the time from the input file though.

Comment: @EdMorton on my screen, $ date --> `Sun Feb 17 18:42:23 +03 2019`, $ who --> `oracle tty1 2019-02-17 00:03 (:0)`, $ uname -r --> `4.1.12.103.9.7.el6uek.x86_64 ` and the above command's result is `oracle Feb 17 18:42`

Comment: Right because systime(() returns the seconds since the epoch for the time when systime() is executed. That';s not what the OP wants though - she wants the time from the output of `who` reformatted so her desired output for the example in your comment would be `oracle Feb 17 00:03`.

Answer (score 0):

Employ `strftime(,mktime())` within `gawk`, using a non-character regular expression *Field Separator* (`-F` flag):

```
your_output |gawk -F'\\W' '
    {print $1 , strftime("%b %d %H:%M",mktime($2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " 00"))}
'
```

Roughly what was said above, alas following with your IO with `mktime()` syntax.

Comment: why the seconds part is defaulted to ````00````

Comment: @stack0114106 they don't have to be defaulted, just they were not present in the OP's data, and are required in `mktime()`'s argument list.

Comment: sry..I get the output as ````root Feb 16 15:00```` and not ````Feb 16 15:29````

Comment: @stack0114106 WOOPS!  The date format tail should be `%H:%M` and not `%H:%S` which would clearly imply seconds...edited.  Cheers.